# aggregate(Max('id')) returns exception 'str' object has no attribute 'email'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to get the user with the highest id but no success.
This is my user model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False)
    name=models.TextField(null=True)
```

Its serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'name')
```

The view:

```
class GetHighestValue(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.aggregate(Max('id'))
```

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on
>   serializer `UserSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'email'.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
     response = self.handle_exception(exc)   
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 201, in get
     return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)   
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 48, in list
     return Response(serializer.data)   
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 674, in data
     ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data   
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 239, in data
     self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)   
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 614, in to_representation
     self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable   
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 463, in to_representation
     attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)   
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 422, in get_attribute
     raise type(exc)(msg) 
     AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`. 
     The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance. 
     Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'email'.
```

Comment: Put the full trace here please

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?  Also, using `latest()` may satisfy your requirements in a simpler way. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest

Comment: Yep, I ran both. I've also tried using latest('id') but it gives me the following error: `'User' object is not iterable`

Comment: what happened if don't use serializer_class?

Comment: If I don't use it it returns this error: `'GetHighestValue' should either include a 'serializer_class' attribute, or override the 'get_serializer_class()' method.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return User.objects.aggregate(Max('id'))
```

The expected return value is a queryset. But aggregate does not return a queryset. Using User.objects.get() does not return a queryset either. The only way to return a queryset, is to use `all()` or `filter()`

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return User.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
```

The all() is implied here and [:1] ensures that you are returning an iterable containing an object rather than a single object.

Comment: I solved the problem yesterday using the order_by, as you did, but I didn't understand why aggregate wasn't working. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is at your view,

when you are trying to get the queryset, you are using a `aggregate()` method.

BUT `aggregate()` not return queryset, but a dictionary of name-value pairs.
see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation for details

Unlike `aggregate()`, `annotate()` is not a terminal clause. The output of the `annotate()` clause is a QuerySet; this QuerySet can be modified using any other QuerySet operation, including `filter()`, `order_by()`.

Hope helpful.

Comment: Can you add the code of how the queryset should be?

Answer (score 1):

I'm expanding on what zhaochy wrote.  Try changing your view's `get_queryset()` method to the below.  Instead of returning the result of the aggregate (not a queryset because it's already been evaluated), we use that number to find the instance associated with the max id and return that (which is a queryset).

```
class GetHighestValue(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        max_id = User.objects.aggregate(Max('id')).get('id__max')
        return User.objects.filter(id=max_id)
```

*Disclaimer: I wrote this post on my phone where I couldn't test it.  Let me know in comments whether this solves your problem and I'll edit as needed.*

Comment: I get the following error: `'User' object is not iterable`
Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, perhaps your project is in a wonky state.  This should work in a fresh Django project.  Query sets are inherently iterable.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: You are returning a single User object when the expected return value is a queryset

Comment: @e4c5 Good catch.  I've updated it to use `filter(...)` instead of `get(...)`.

Comment: You probably don't want to do this: it does two queries: one of which will aggregate all items over the whole table, the other which fetches the object. Use the `.order_by('-id')[:1]` instead.